# CXF 3 Cache Level

Tags: java, spring, jms, cxf

In *CXF 2* I could set the level like this:

```
<jaxws:client name="client">
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfigFeature">
            <property name="jmsConfig" ref="jmsConfig"/>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:client>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

However, in *CXF 3* `cacheLevel` property is missing in `org.apache.cxf.transport.jms.JMSConfiguration`.

How can I set the cache level in *CXF 3*?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF 3 does not use the spring `MessageListenerContainer` anymore. 
So there is no `cachelevel` setting. CXF 3 has improved the performance over CXF 2, thus this setting is not needed any more.

Answer (score 0):

This option was removed since CXF 3.0.0.

Specify the level of caching that the JMS listener container is allowed to apply. 
Please check out the java doc of the `org.springframework.jms.listenerDefaultMessageListenerContainer` for more information. Default is -1.

Check this link:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-the-jmsconfigfeature.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I've already checked this link out. The problem is that cacheLevel property was removed from JMSConfiguration. But DefaultMessageListenerContainer still has this property. Thought that cxf creates DefaultMessageListenerContainer bean on the runtime but it doesn't